# How to see all the line in shell script?

Tags: linux, unix

One of my shell script file has 900 lines. I can't able to see first 700 lines while using cat command. How can I see entire file content using cat command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try to use `more` or `less` commands?
Their advantage is that they allow you to scroll the file even its very long.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the entire file. You can use the less command.

```
     less filename
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use less or more command utility for the same